# Closure of $\{\frac{1}{n}\}:=M$

Tags: general-topology

In $\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology the closure of the above set $M$ is $M \cup 0$. I fail showing this by purely topological means. I.e. not using the fact that this holds in the reals as a metric space and deduce it for the induced topology.

I assumed that there exist a closed subset $A$ containing $M$ but not 0. Hence, the complement of $A$ is an open subset containing 0. Does this already yield a contradiction or do I need a different approach?

Could you help me on this?

Comment: You need some sort of structure on the topology to guarantee $0$ is a limit point (such as the metric). Otherwise you can just take the discrete topology, and then $0$ is not a limit point of any sequence except eventually constant sequences (and even then, only those that are eventually $0$).

Comment: I would like to use the standard topology $\mathbb{R}$, I should have stated this. In the book I read they say that every closed set containing M must also contain 0. If not its complement is an open neighborhood of 0 that does not intersect with M. I don't see why this is contradicting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I want to note that proving the closure of $M$ is $M\cup \{0\}$ by considering it as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean metric and considering limit points really is exactly the same as proving the same statement with $M$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology induced by the Euclidean metric, which is the distinction you appear to be drawing. It sounds like what you are asking for is a way to prove that $Cl(M)=M\cup \{0\}$ without using that theorem directly.

The closure of $M$ is the 'smallest' closed set containing it, with respect to your topology. That is, $$Cl(M)=\bigcap_{A \supseteq M,A \text{ closed}}A$$
So there are two statements to prove: That $M \cup \{0\}$ is closed, and that every $A \supseteq M$ that is closed contains $0$. Well to show $M \cup \{0\}$ is closed we look at its complement in $\mathbb{R}$: it consists of the union of:

- The open sets $(1,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$
- The open sets $(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

So it is the union of open sets and therefore open.

Now suppose $A \supset M$ is closed, and does not contain $0$. So its complement is open, and its complement contains $0$. By definition of openness, for some $\varepsilon >0$ we can guarantee that every $x$ with $d(0,x)<\varepsilon$ is in the complement of $M$. But this clearly contradicts the Archimedean property of the reals - I can always choose an $N>1/\varepsilon$ with $1/N$ in the complement of $M$. So $A$ contains $0$.

Comment: That's exactly what I was aiming at! Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to modify my initial question to make it more precise.